# Scala Option return type

Tags: scala

I am newbie in Scala programming world but loving it. Recently I have started porting my research App into Scala and one of thing I am still struggling is the return keyword. For example in below code

```
def readDocument(dbobj:MongoDBObject) = Option[ContainerMetaData] 
{
  for(a <- dbobj.getAs[String]("classname");
      b <- dbobj.getAs[Long]("id"); 
      c <- dbobj.getAs[Long]("version");
      d <- dbobj.getAs[String]("description");
      e <- dbobj.getAs[String]("name");
      f <- dbobj.getAs[String]("tag");
      g <- dbobj.getAs[Int]("containertype");
      h <- dbobj.getAs[Date]("createddate")
  )
  {
      val ctype = ContainerType(g)
      val jodadt = new DateTime(h) 
      val data = new ContainerMetaData(a,b,c,d,e,f,ctype,jodadt)
      Some(data)
  }
  None
}
```

In above code I get the error message:

```
type mismatch;  found   : None.type  required: om.domain.ContainerMetaData
```

So if I remove the explicit return type the code works but then without explicit return keyword I am not able to terminate my code at `Some(data)`.

```
def readDocument(dbobj:MongoDBObject)= 
{
  for(a <- dbobj.getAs[String]("classname");
      b <- dbobj.getAs[Long]("id"); 
      c <- dbobj.getAs[Long]("version");
      d <- dbobj.getAs[String]("description");
      e <- dbobj.getAs[String]("name");
      f <- dbobj.getAs[String]("tag");
      g <- dbobj.getAs[Int]("containertype");
      h <- dbobj.getAs[Date]("createddate")
  )
  {
      val ctype = ContainerType(g)
      val jodadt = new DateTime(h) 
      val data = new ContainerMetaData(a,b,c,d,e,f,ctype,jodadt)
      Some(data)
  }
  None
}
```

And if add a return keyword then compiler complains

```
method `readDocument` has return statement; needs result tye
```

Few more additional info, this is the trait I am extending

```
trait MongoDAOSerializer[T] {
    def createDocument(content:T) :  DBObject
    def readDocument(db:MongoDBObject) : Option[T]
}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure the return type is `Option[ContainerMetaData]` and you need `def readDocument(...): Option[ContainerMetaData] = { for...yield... }`

Comment: The rule for beginning Scala programmers is "don't use `return`!"

Comment: @RandallSchulz This question isn't really about `return` at all!

Comment: The OP mentions using it a few times even though none of the code samples show it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is, that you are missing the `yield` keyword in the for-comprehension. And also the `None` at the end is unnecessary, as the for-comprehension will yield `None`, if one of the values is missing and also the explicit creation of a `Some` in the comprehension is not needed, as it will create an `Option` anyway. Your code hase to look like this (not tested)

```
def readDocument(dbobj: MongoDBObject): Option[ContainerMetaData] = {
  for {
      a <- dbobj.getAs[String]("classname")
      b <- dbobj.getAs[Long]("id")
      c <- dbobj.getAs[Long]("version")
      d <- dbobj.getAs[String]("description")
      e <- dbobj.getAs[String]("name")
      f <- dbobj.getAs[String]("tag")
      g <- dbobj.getAs[Int]("containertype")
      h <- dbobj.getAs[Date]("createddate")
  } yield {
      val ctype = ContainerType(g)
      val jodadt = new DateTime(h) 
      new ContainerMetaData(a,b,c,d,e,f,ctype,jodadt)
  }
}
```

Comment: You fixed it so it would.  Before you had the `for` as an argument to the `Option` companion object apply method, so it would have been doubly wrapped.

Comment: Yes, I just copied it from the OP and didn't see that at first. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Deleted my original comment to avoid confusion.  The current scheme should work!